# RSS Icon at browser's address bar

Tags: views, feeds

I m not using Drupal 7 with its default way. I don't publish in front page, since I use a view for the front page.
I produce an RSS feed from a view.

How I can make the RSS icons appear at browsers' address bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a custom module, you can use [drupal_add_feed](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_feed/7), should work for both D6 and D7:

```
function CUSTOM_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  drupal_add_feed(url('path/to/feed'), 'Feed Title');
  $vars['head'] = drupal_get_html_head();
}
```

Comment: Hello Tostinni, I am new to Drupal API, can you tell me where to put this code and where to call it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to attach the feed to the page display.

It's an option in the feed configuration.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but the problem is that i don't have a page view on it. It is just a feed/rss view and I want its icon be sitewide.